# Bulk INSERT or UPDATE ignoring errors in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For bulk loading imported data I make some processing and store the result of that processing in a staging table. Then, I can apply changes to other tables using the staged data.

This works perfectly when the imported data is correct, but sometimes it may contain **errors such as references to unexisting foreign keys or duplication of primary keys**.

I would like to achieve something similar as the following example (which works when the data has no errors), but **instead of failing** the whole operation, I would like to **log the conflictive rows and continue processing**.

#### Example

Let's suppose I have an `items` table and an `items_operations` staging table. Then, after populating `items_operations` I can...

**Create new items**

```
INSERT INTO items (id, name, manufacturer_id, price)
SELECT
  item_id,
  item_name,
  item_manufacturer_id
  item_price
FROM items_operations
WHERE operation = 'creation'
```

(This might fail if there is a duplicate `id` or unexisting FK for `manufactuer_id`)

**Update existing items**

```
UPDATE items t1
SET (name, manufacturer_id, price) =
    (SELECT
        t2.item_name,
        t2.item_manufacturer_id,
        t2.item_price
    FROM items_operations t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.item_id
        AND t2.operation = 'modification')
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM items_operations t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.item_id
    AND t2.operation = 'modification')
```

(This will fail in the case of unexisting FK for `manufacturer_id`)

#### Additional remarks

- Since **SQL** operations must be atomic, I think that what I need maybe would require use of **PL/SQL**, but I'm not quite sure about what approach should I follow.
- Also, it might be important to know that my `items` table is really huge (~300MM records), so unnecesary joins should be avoided.
- Finally, sometimes `items_operations` contains updates for unexisting items (there is no `id` on `items` matching `item_id`). This does not fail, but it would be ideal if I could be able to log those unmatched items, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [DML error logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2)

Create the error table (once per table that you are loading)

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log( dml_table_name => 'ITEMS' );
end;
/
```

Then you can use the `LOG ERRORS INTO` clause

```
INSERT INTO items (id, name, manufacturer_id, price)
   SELECT
      item_id,
      item_name,
      item_manufacturer_id
      item_price
 FROM items_operations
WHERE operation = 'creation'
  LOG ERRORS INTO err$_items
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Then you can query `err$_items` to see the errors that were thrown.

For things that are not failures (i.e. items in `item_operations` that do not have a matching row in `items`), you'd need to run a query to find those.  Going forward, I would define a foreign key constraint that prevents you from recording operations on non-existent items.

Comment: I don't think that works -- DML error logging does not work for statements that trigger unique constraint violations.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this approach will not work with the errors that I have. The link you shared in your answer says DML error logging doesn't work when: "Deferred constraints are violated, Direct-path INSERT or MERGE operations raise unique constraint or index violations and UPDATE or MERGE operations raise a unique constraint or index violation"

Comment: @Sam - None of the operations you listed would use a direct path operation.  If your constraints are deferred, you wouldn't get an error until you committed rather than when the statements were executed so I assume your constraints are not deferred.  If your `update` violates a unique constraint, that would be an issue but it sounds like you are concerned that it may violate a foreign key constraint.  That should be logged.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not reallly sure about what deferred constraints and direct-path operations are (I'm reading about that as I write this comment). I'll try your solution and update you on how it works ;)

Comment: @JustinCave I tried it and it worked, but I had to add the `reject limit unlimited` option to the `LOG ERRORS` command. I'll edit that and accept your answer.